# Cannot use BatchQuery in a paged result handler class

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-python-driver

Python driver provides with a event/callback approach for large results:

https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html

Also, there is a BatchQuery class to use with ORM and it's quite handy:

https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/batches.html?highlight=batchquery

Now, I need to execute BatchQuery in callback handlers of Paged Result object but script just stucks on iterating on current page.

I guess this is due to impossibility of sharing cassandra sessions between threads, while BatchQuery and the "paged result" approach are using threading to manage event settings and callback calls.

Any idea on how to magically sort this situation out? Below you can find some code:

```
# paged.py
class PagedQuery:
    """
    Class to manage paged results.
    >>> query = "SELECT * FROM ks.my_table WHERE collectionid=123 AND ttype='collected'"  # define query
    >>> def handler(page):  # define result page handler function
    ...     for t in page:
    ...         print(t)
    >>> pq = PagedQuery(query, handler)  # instantiate a PagedQuery object
    >>> pq.finished_event.wait()  # wait for the PagedQuery to handle all results
    >>> if pq.error:
    ...     raise pq.error
    """
    def __init__(self, query, handler=None):
        session = new_cassandra_session()
        session.row_factory = named_tuple_factory
        statement = SimpleStatement(query, fetch_size=500)
        future = session.execute_async(statement)
        self.count = 0
        self.error = None
        self.finished_event = Event()
        self.query = query
        self.session = session
        self.handler = handler
        self.future = future
        self.future.add_callbacks(
            callback=self.handle_page,
            errback=self.handle_error
        )

    def handle_page(self, page):
        if not self.handler:
            raise RuntimeError('A page handler function was not defined for the query')
        self.handler(page)

        if self.future.has_more_pages:
            self.future.start_fetching_next_page()
        else:
            self.finished_event.set()

    def handle_error(self, exc):
        self.error = exc
        self.finished_event.set()

# main.py
# script using class above
def main():

    query = 'SELECT * FROM ks.my_table WHERE collectionid=10 AND ttype=\'collected\''

    def handle_page(page):

        b = BatchQuery(batch_type=BatchType.Unlogged)
        for obj in page:
            process(obj)  # some updates on obj...
            obj.batch(b).save()

        b.execute()

    pq = PagedQuery(query, handle_page)
    pq.finished_event.wait()

    if not pq.count:
        print('Empty queryset. Please, check parameters')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: From python cassandra driver guys at Datastax:

"you cannot execute statements inside a query callback. I think this is the issue you are experiencing. You cannot execute statements in the handle_page function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due the fact you cannot execute queries in the event loop of ResponseFuture, you can just iterate and send objects to queues. We do have kafka queues to persist objects but in this case a thread safe Python Queue works well.

```
import sys
import datetime
import queue
import threading
import logging

from cassandra.connection import Event
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster, default_lbp_factory, NoHostAvailable
from cassandra.cqlengine.connection import (Connection, DEFAULT_CONNECTION, _connections)
from cassandra.query import named_tuple_factory, PreparedStatement, SimpleStatement
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.util import OrderedMapSerializedKey
from cassandra.cqlengine.query import BatchQuery
from smfrcore.models.cassandra import Tweet

STOP_QUEUE = object()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)


def new_cassandra_session():
    retries = 5
    _cassandra_user = 'user'
    _cassandra_password = 'xxxx'
    while retries >= 0:
        try:
            cluster_kwargs = {'compression': True,
                          'load_balancing_policy': default_lbp_factory(),
                          'executor_threads': 10,
                          'idle_heartbeat_interval': 10,
                          'idle_heartbeat_timeout': 30,
                          'auth_provider': PlainTextAuthProvider(username=_cassandra_user, password=_cassandra_password)}

            cassandra_cluster = Cluster(**cluster_kwargs)
            cassandra_session = cassandra_cluster.connect()
            cassandra_session.default_timeout = None
            cassandra_session.default_fetch_size = 500
            cassandra_session.row_factory = named_tuple_factory
            cassandra_default_connection = Connection.from_session(DEFAULT_CONNECTION, session=cassandra_session)
            _connections[DEFAULT_CONNECTION] = cassandra_default_connection
            _connections[str(cassandra_session)] = cassandra_default_connection
        except (NoHostAvailable, Exception) as e:
            print('Cassandra host not available yet...sleeping 10 secs: ', str(e))
            retries -= 1
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            return cassandra_session


class PagedQuery:
    """
    Class to manage paged results.
    >>> query = "SELECT * FROM ks.my_table WHERE collectionid=123 AND ttype='collected'"  # define query
    >>> def handler(page):  # define result page handler function
    ...     for t in page:
    ...         print(t)
    >>> pq = PagedQuery(query, handler)  # instantiate a PagedQuery object
    >>> pq.finished_event.wait()  # wait for the PagedQuery to handle all results
    >>> if pq.error:
    ...     raise pq.error
    """
    def __init__(self, query, handler=None):
        session = new_cassandra_session()
        session.row_factory = named_tuple_factory
        statement = SimpleStatement(query, fetch_size=500)
        future = session.execute_async(statement)
        self.count = 0
        self.error = None
        self.finished_event = Event()
        self.query = query
        self.session = session
        self.handler = handler
        self.future = future
        self.future.add_callbacks(
            callback=self.handle_page,
            errback=self.handle_error
        )

    def handle_page(self, page):
        if not self.handler:
            raise RuntimeError('A page handler function was not defined for the query')
        self.handler(page)

        if self.future.has_more_pages:
            self.future.start_fetching_next_page()
        else:
            self.finished_event.set()

    def handle_error(self, exc):
        self.error = exc
        self.finished_event.set()



def main():

    query = 'SELECT * FROM ks.my_table WHERE collectionid=1 AND ttype=\'collected\''

    q = queue.Queue()
    threads = []

    def worker():
        nonlocal q
        local_counter = 0
        b = BatchQuery(batch_type=BatchType.Unlogged)
        while True:
            tweet = q.get()

            if tweet is STOP_QUEUE:
                b.execute()

                logging.info(' >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Executed last batch for this worker!!!!')
                break

            tweet.batch(b).save()
            local_counter += 1
            if not (local_counter % 500):
                b.execute()
                logging.info('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Batch executed in this worker: geotagged so far:', str(local_counter))
                b = BatchQuery(batch_type=BatchType.Unlogged)  # reset batch

            q.task_done()

    def handle_page(page):

        for obj in page:
            process(obj)  # some updates on obj...
            q.put(obj)

    pq = PagedQuery(query, handle_page)
    pq.finished_event.wait()
    # block until all tasks are done
    q.join()

    # stop workers by sending sentinel value (None)
    for i in range(4):
        q.put(STOP_QUEUE)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    if pq.error:
        raise pq.error

    if not pq.count:
        print('Empty queryset. Please, check parameters')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```